# How do I turn off all the image processing to see actual, unmodified pixels when I zoom way in?

Tags: ios, image, antialiasing

I have an app that needs to zoom far enough into images that I can clearly see the individual pixels on an image.  I need to see clear squares of one color, with no anti-aliasing or other of the usually-helpful techniques for making images look good on a display.  How do I stifle all this help?  Here is code that works, but zooms into blurry, adjusted pixels:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect photoRect = CGRectMake(currentTarget.origin.x,
                                  currentTarget.origin.y,
                                  currentTarget.size.width,
                                  currentTarget.size.height);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ;
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGImageRef subImageRef = 
        CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImage.CGImage, photoRect);
    UIImage *subImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImageRef];
    [subImage drawInRect:rect];
    CGImageRelease(subImageRef);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    CGContextFlush(context);
}
```

Comment: have you tried drawing the `CGImage` directly with `CGContextDrawImage`?

Comment: i have, with varying battles to get the location and scaling right. what's there is very simple and readable, but perhaps not at the right level. if you have suggested replacement code doing that it would be fine.

Comment: Clearly, the context code is a NOOP at present. A dreg of previous tries, or a foreshadowing of the eventual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the interpolation quality for the context should help resolve this issue, although if you're allowing the user to zoom beyond the 1:1 pixel ratio, things will still look somewhat soft.

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone)
```

In this instance, I've used `kCGInterpolationNone` which is effectively "nearest neighbour".

For more information see [Apple's reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455656-cgcontextsetinterpolationquality).

Comment: @BillCheswick Irrelevant/doubtless none of my business, but are you working on something related to pixel art or similar?

Comment: Not this time. I am implementing an old idea of mine, "zoompass", an image/map-based password system based on zooming into very large maps, images, etc., selecting a point possibly as deep as a pixel, and generating a password from it. i got a patent for this idea, and decided it was worth releasing to the world in an app to try it out.  I needed crisp pixels for this. Pixel editing would be a fine application of your answer.

Comment: @BillCheswick Cool, that sounds like an interesting application - hope all goes well. :-)

Comment: I've been having fun with it, and you saved me some of my valuable "retirement" time.  Look for "zoompass" in the app store some time before Usenix Security.